# OpenCV functions are slower in Android 5.0 than in 4.4.0

Tags: android, opencv, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, opencv3.0

I'm doing a project using **Android 4.4** and **OpenCV 3.0** in cell Lg G3. I updated the device for **Android 5.0** and found that the OpenCV functions were much slower. I've done some research and found nothing relevant. Could someone suggest a possible problem?

Thank you!

Comment: google says that android 5 uses ART but android 4 uses Dalvik. According to http://www.embedded.com/design/programming-languages-and-tools/4406164/Developing-OpenCV-computer-vision-apps-for-the-Android-platform , OpenCV uses Dalvik. I've no idea whether this could explain the problem or not, since I didnt develop for mobiles yet.

Comment: Hello @Micka, thank you for your answer.

Both Art and Dalvik are virtual machines that in theory are transparent to the opencv. However, this virtual machine modification may be the answer. The purpose of Art is to accelerate applications and reduce battery consumption, but saw some comparative application and not always the art is faster than dalvilk.